# Java Robot Class Not Working In Programs other than Eclipse

Tags: java, awtrobot

I have a basic Java program to move the mouse back and forth:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.delay(2000);
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    r.mouseMove(50, 500);
    r.delay(500);
    r.mouseMove(50, 600);
    r.delay(500);
}
```

When I run the program with eclipse open, the mouse moves correctly across the screen. However, when I focus on another progam, i.e. Internet Explorer after I start the program, the program does not move the mouse at all unless I switch back to Eclipse.

Any idea why is the Robot Class only working when the Eclipse IDE is the window open?
Is this a software bug or an hardware issue, and if so, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern windows operating systems Eclipse will have to be launched in an administration mode to be able to simulate mouse and button operations outside of itself. Please right click eclipse and select 'run as administrator' and let us know if that helped you.